# getting a wav file from a mic while also using it to record a zoom call

Tags: microphone, video, wav, zoom, aac-m4a

I have a project in which I'll be using a Blue Yeti X (or something like it, podcasting type mic) as a mic on a macOS computer and recording people on it using Zoom.

I want linked audio and video files, and I want the audio to be a wav file. When Zoom records meetings, it's spits out its audio file as a m4a, which is a bit lossy, I can convert it to wav after the fact. But it would be better to just record a wav on the mic (which the blue yeti can do). However I need that wav file to be synced to the video file that zoom is going to put out.

Is there some way I can record on the mic independently from zoom but still have it synced to the video I'll be recording through Zoom?

Comment: At least tell us what OS you're using. This stuff tends to be easier on Mac, but I think might be possible on Win [we have a few routing questions on here but I don't think anyone's ever come back to say what worked on Win.] Nix, I know nothing about.

Comment: edited, thank you. On the end with the mic it it's a macOS, I'll be recording on the other end on a windows PC through Zoom

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting what you're trying to do… mic in Mac, transmit over zoom to PC, record in PC? Where do you want to record the wav?